# Page not refreshing after res.redirect(303, '/') done after DELETE request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I've managed to redirect a page after a DELETE request to the home GET route, but the page isn't actually refreshing (i.e. the deleted item still appears) and it isn't until I manually refresh the page that it is removed. I've done some console.logs and the item has definitely been deleted by the time it has redirected to .get('/'). Any ideas why this isn't working?

**app.js - routes only**

```
app.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM todos', (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
            console.log('Todos read from database');
            res.render('home', { results: results });
        });
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        const todoItem = req.body.todo;

        connection.query('INSERT INTO todos (todo) VALUES (?)', todoItem, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Todo inserted into database.');
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    })
    .delete((req, res) => {
        const todo = req.body.todoItem;

        connection.query('DELETE FROM todos WHERE todo=?', todo, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Todo deleted from database.');
        });
        res.redirect(303, '/');
    });
```

**client.js**

```
'use strict';

let todoItems = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');

for (let i = 0; i < todoItems.length; i++) {
    todoItems[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

function handleClick(e) {
    const todoTag = e.target.closest('.todo-item');
    const todoItem = todoTag.getElementsByClassName('todo')[0].innerText;

    const clickeTodo = {
        todoItem: todoItem
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify(clickeTodo),
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**Terminal output**

```
Todo deleted from database.
[ RowDataPacket { todo: 'Clean' }, RowDataPacket { todo: 'Read' } ]
Todos read from database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that fetch won't send the browser to a new page if it gets a redirect response and this needs to be done on the client side instead. I've added window.location = response.url and it now works:

```
'use strict';

let todoItems = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');

for (let i = 0; i < todoItems.length; i++) {
    todoItems[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

function handleClick(e) {
    const todoTag = e.target.closest('.todo-item');
    const todoItem = todoTag.getElementsByClassName('todo')[0].innerText;

    const clickeTodo = {
        todoItem: todoItem
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify(clickeTodo),
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    })
        .then(response => {
            window.location = response.url;
            response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```